# oracle - how to copy partitioned table to a new schema on new tablespace

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracle11g, database-partitioning

I created a datapump export (Oracle 11g) from `SCHEMA A` on a partitioned table (tablespace ``` TEST``) using ```TABLE=MYPARTTBL:MYPART`.

I created a new schema `SCHEMA B` and imported the dump of SCHEMA A's partitioned table with success, but it created the table using the same tablespace `TEST`.

What I need to do is import the partitioned table to a different tablespace `TEST_NEW`.

What's a good way to do this? Considering now, that I have a copy of SCHEMA A's partitioned table in SCHEMA B.

Here's my export parfile parameters:

```
DIRECTORY=DW_PUMP
TABLES=MRA.FACT_USE:P_20111009
DUMPFILE=MRA.TBLPART-20111209.dmp
LOGFILE=MRA.TBLPART-20111209.log
```

Comment: are you using datapump or normal export ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the REMAP_TABLESPACE parameter when importing:
REMAP_TABLESPACE=TEST:TEST_NEW

Comment: Thanks. Works nicely. There seems to be a lot of nice features with 11g.